# Send File via javascript to server spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, spring-mvc, servlets

I need to upload a image to a server in Spring, the code i have is this one where I get the file:

```
var file = $("#form-field-photo").get(0).files[0];
```

Then i have tried some ways to post it but it didnt work, maybe because i dont declare correctly the controller but i am not sure.

I need to send it without form or any external plugin, the controller is implemented as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/setProfilePhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void setProfilePhoto(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edit: OUCH! read "Without external plugin" first now. Sorry!

USing Valums-file uploader

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('btnToStartImport'),
            action: '/webservice.ashx',
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg'],
            debug: true,
            onSubmit: function () {
                uploader.setParams({
                    paramdate: $(myDate)
                })
            },
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseText) {

                //DoStuff

            }
        });
```

[Valums-file uploader](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader)

Answer (score 0):

**Using AJAX.** 
Try this http://pauliusmatulionis.blogspot.com/2013/10/spring-mvc-ajax-file-upload.html There is a example controller method in it.